# Trying to pass variable to window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, hash

Having some difficulty getting this to work.

Using a javascript dictionary to create an assignment list, there two elements: text (the title) and text2 (a hash anchor link, ex-#slowshutter)
But I can't seem to get the link to work.

```
 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "viewButton";
        element2.value = todoDictionary["text"];
        var link= todoDictionary["text2"];
        element2.id = rowID;
        element2.setAttribute("onclick","window.location.hash = link");
        element2.className = "viewButton";
        cell2.appendChild(element2);
```

I've tried a variety of other ways that I found it shown here on stack overflow, but they don't seem to be working as nothing happens.

example 
"window.location.hash = 'link'" nothign happens
"window.location.hash='+ link'" gives an error as it uses "+ link" in the url.

If i put the link directly in, it works fine: example "window.location.hash='#slowshutter'"

I know the link is stored properly in the "text2" as I tested it for the element2.value instead of "text" and it came up with "#slowshutter" instead of the title...

Any ideas?

Noel

Comment: "window.location.hash = ' + link + "'"

Comment: `element2.onclick = function() { window.location.hash = link };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably want

```
element2.onclick=function(){ window.location.hash = link; };
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Since you are using the attribute api, you are probably not actually attaching the event.

Comment: one last item if you dont mind. 
In the list, when I click on the item title, it temporarily brings up the keyboard before going to the link. I assume it's because it is an "input" item. I tried "label" and "text area" instead but the title doesn't show. any way to make it so it's just text and not a text input box?